# Object property change is not saved after streaming in java

Tags: java, io, objectoutputstream

Update:
OK so I've grayed out parts of code and found what was causing the problem.
I've added here 3 lines of code with the comment "this is the added code that causes the problem".

### But I still don't understand why it affects the result.

I am working on a client-server application that sends data objects via ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream.

I noticed something strange that made me think I might not fully understand object referencing.

On the client side I have a method that creates and returns a User object:

```
private static User createNewUser()
{
    User newUser = new User();

    newUser.name = "Jim";
    newUser.phone = "054-6885644";
    ..

    return newUser;
}
```

I create a User object using this method, change one of its properties and send it to the server:

```
User user = createNewUser();

out.writeObject(user); // this is the added code that causes the problem
out.flush(); // this is the added code that causes the problem

system.out.println("old phone number: " + user.phone); // this prints out 054-6885644
user.phone = "052-9008801";
system.out.println("new phone number: " + user.phone); // this prints out 052-9008801

out.writeObject(user);
out.flush();
```

On the server side I read the object:

```
User user = (User) in.readObject(); // this is the added code that causes the problem

User newProfile = (User) in.readObject();
System.out.println("phone number: " + newProfile.phone); // this prints out 054-6885644 (why??)
```

So, as you can see, before I stream the object, the propery was updated. But after the server deserializes it, it gets the original property value.
Why is that?

By the way, I tried cloning the object before streaming it (creating an entirely different object and just copying the fields) and it worked - the propery value did not revert.

So why is this happening? Why does the change to the referenced object's property not saved after streaming?

Comment: I replicated this on my system, using 2 different projects, and the server printed out the new number. Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces the same problem, to ensure it's not a problem with other code you might be writing.

Comment: @VinceEmigh, thank you for your ecomment. I've added the 3 lines of code that replicate the problem.

Comment: Objects sent through the stream are cached. When you send the object a second time, I believe the OOS is using the cached value instead of the object with the new phone value. Try calling `out.reset()` before sending the object a second time. If this works, let me know and ill put it as an answer

Comment: @VinceEmigh, this indeed solved the problem. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you output an object using [`writeObject(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object)), the instance will be serialized (as expected). The problem is, the serialized version will be cached, and any time you attempt to write that same instance a second time, the cached version of the serialized instance is referenced.

To avoid this, you can either call [`reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset()) after calling `writeObject(Object)`, or you could use [`writeUnshared(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared(java.lang.Object))